# Unable to fire a "click" event - please provide a DOM element - Radio button JestJs

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm writing tests to click on the value "green" radio button using Jest and React. I am facing an error

Radio Button:
`<input id="multicolored" name="colours" type="radio" value="green"> id="radioButton" aria-label="Radio Button" name="radio-button-field">`

Radio Test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Colors from './colors';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

test('It should click on radio button', async () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const dom = render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Colors />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    div
  );

  var input = dom.getByLabelText('Radio Button');
  fireEvent.click(input, { target: { value: 'green' } });
});
```

But I am facing an error. "Unable to fire a "click" event - please provide a DOM element."

Am I missing something or is there another way I can click on radio button using fireEvent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On radio types you should use **change** instead of **click** in fireEvent.

```
fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'green' } });
```

Hint: It is recommend to use screen to find the elements:

```
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

const radio = screen.getByLabelText('Radio Button');
```

DOM Testing Library also exports a screen object which has every query that is pre-bound to document.body (using the within functionality). Wrappers such as React Testing Library re-export screen so you can use it the same way. You can check on [testing-library documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#screen).